# Ruby function to fetch, filter, and generate data

Tags: ruby, cyclomatic-complexity

I'm currently writing a script and I decided to run cane over it to look for some issues, and the following method was highlighted. I've done my best to cut it back, and at this point I'm inclined to leave it as-is, however cane is still giving it a pretty high rating of 23 (15 is the point it starts complaining) so I wanted to get some more input. Other than perhaps splitting fetching and generating does anyone have any ideas?

```
def self.generate(template, output_file, company)
  puts 'Fetching data...'
  @data = Provider::GenericProvider.create_provider(company['type'].to_sym, company).data

  valid_keys = @data.keys.sort {|a,b| -(a <=> b)}[0,10]
  @data = @data.select {|k, _| valid_keys.include? k}

  valid_keys = @data.keys.sort {|a,b| -(a <=> b)}[0,2]

  loop do
    break if :done == choose {|menu| timesheet_menu valid_keys, menu}
  end

  puts 'Generating output...'
  # Used as a result of the ERB binding
  #noinspection RubyUnusedLocalVariable
  data = @data.select {|k, _| valid_keys.include? k}
  File.write(output_file, ERB.new(File.read(template), nil, '-').result(binding))
end
```

**EDIT:**

I just split it, and ended up with the below function, which still scores 19 due to the various lambdas used to control sorting and filtering the data despite being pretty easy to follow still:

```
def self.fetch_data(company)
  data = Provider::GenericProvider.create_provider(company['type'].to_sym, company).data

  valid_keys = data.keys.sort {|a,b| -(a <=> b)}[0,10]
  data = data.select {|k, _| valid_keys.include? k}

  valid_keys = data.keys.sort {|a,b| -(a <=> b)}[0,2]

  loop do
    break if :done == choose {|menu| timesheet_menu data, valid_keys, menu}
  end

  data.select {|k, _| valid_keys.include? k}
end
```

Comment: I did an edit based on your "final code", though I confess I'm not familiar with that term.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Fixed that too :)

Comment: I have rolled back revisions that were based on an answer. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matthew, it appears to me that you are only making use of the two elements of `data` whose keys are the top two in the sort.  Please correct me if I am wrong.  If that is the case, I believe your code (after "edit") can be simplified to this:

```
  def self.fetch_data(company)
    data = Provider::GenericProvider.create_provider(company['type'].to_sym, company).data
    data = data.sort {|(k1,_),(k2,_)| -(k1<=>k2)}.first(2)
    loop do
      break if :done == choose {|menu| timesheet_menu data, data.map(&:first), menu}
    end
    Hash[data]
  end
```

Note that after the sort, `data` is an array of two 2-tuples, each corresponding to a key-value pair from the original hash.  If I misunderstood what you are doing, and you do need to pull out the 10 elements of the hash corresponding to the 10 highest-ranking keys, just change the parameter for `first` from 2 to 10, then extract the first two elements when you need them (i.e., `data.first(2)`).  You can then retrieve the key values from these 2-tuples or convert `data.first(2)` to a hash for the return value, as I have done with `data`.

Edit: Ah, `valid_keys` is modified by `choose`. Consider this as a further possibility:

```
 data = Hash[data.sort{|(a, _), (b, _)| -(a <=> b)}.first(10)]

 loop do
   break if (keys_chosen = choose {|menu| timesheet_menu data, data.keys.first(2), menu})
 end

 data.select {|k, _| keys_chosen.include? k}
```

Comment: The first sort/filter applies filters the data to the latest 10 entries (the keys are dates in ISO format; somewhat irrelevant, but context). `valid_keys` is initialised to the first two elements initially, `choose ... timesheet_menu` is a `Highline` menu that then displays a menu to the user and asks them which they'd like to use which modifies `valid_keys` as a side effect.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get it down to a score of 14 which puts it below the normal cutoff for warnings using some of the suggestions here. I've included the final code in a further edit to the question if you're interested.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Highline#choose` is beyond my control, so I can't implement it this way. The reason for the loop at all is because `#choose` will only handle a single answer from the user, which toggles one of the options on or off (handled by `#timesheet_menu`), and then returns the option chosen as well. `:done` is the option that signifies the user has finished their modifications which drops out of the loop and continues the main logic. See http://highline.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/HighLine.html#M000011 for more on the `Highline` gem. Anyway, thanks a lot for the input.

Comment: Instead of `.sort{|(a, _), (b, _)| -(a <=> b)}.first(10)` I would use `.sort_by(&:first)}.last(10).reverse`.

Comment: I hadn't considered that, @Nak, (and have tucked it away) but I have a slight preference for what I have.  My scorecard has them tied on readability, but the incumbent has the edge on simplicity and (I'm guessing) efficiency.

Comment: @Cary, @Nakilon: I actually prefer a minor modification of tokland's version below: `.sort_by {|key, _| key}.last(10).reverse`. It has the benefits of nak's version being a straight forward, obvious solution and the benefit of the block giving it a very explicit sort order for clarities sake instead of relying on the knowledge that the hash gets split into tuples.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken the code labeled as "final revision" in your question. Some notes:

- `data = something` and then `data = another_thing`. So `data` holds two different values, that's confusing (use another variable name).
- Spaces between lines: Vertical space is very valuable, don't insert blank lines without a reason (for example, to separate logically different parts of the code).
- `sort_by` is usually a better option than `sort` (higher level of abstraction).
- `xs[0, 2]` -> xs.first(2). More declarative.
- `break if :done == choose ...`. Is that a Yoda-condition? it does not look idiomatic in Ruby.

I'd write:

```
def self.fetch_data(company)
  provider = Provider::GenericProvider.create_provider(company['type'].to_sym, company)
  data = Hash[provider.data.sort_by { |key, value| key }.reverse.first(10)]
  valid_keys = data.keys.first(2)
  until (choose { |menu| timesheet_menu(data, valid_keys, menu) }) == :done
  end
  data.keys & valid_keys
end
```

Comment: Regarding your return value, is that the same as the select given? In particular, does it return a hash? It looks like it'd just return the keys when I want both. As to `#choose`... it's taking user input and modifying valid_keys based on it. So, technically no it's not the same arguments. At any rate, as addressed with Cary, choose is provided by Highline so I can't really mess with that too much.

Comment: Oh, you are right, you want a hash as output. Activesupport has an abstraction for that task, are by chance using it? (i.e. Rails).

Comment: Nope, this is a console app.

Comment: Also, since people (ie. you) seem to still be interested, I bumped the version of the code in the post with what I'm currently using (updated with suggestions from you)